# Change color of data label placed, using the 'best fit' option, outside a pie chart - Excel 2010

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, pie-chart

I am working with a pie chart whose data labels are added using the `best fit` property. Most of those labels are placed by Excel inside the pie, but some of them are placed outside.

Because of some series colors are so strong, the data labels had to be defined as white. Of course, the labels placed outside the pie wont be visible if I don't manually change their color (to black, for instance)

What I am trying to do is to conditionally change the label's color according to where Excel placed it (white inside the pie, black outside it), as in the following image:

[image: Change data label color according to position in Pie chart]

I have been searching for a solution, but it seems that nobody had a similar problem.

Does anyone know if Excel allows this or does someone know a trick to bypass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this in Excel.

- When you click on the chart, and go to `Layout` under `Chart Tools`.
- Once there, go to `Data Labels`.
- When you click on that, it will display a drop-down menu. At the bottom of the menu, click on `More Data Label Options`.
- It will pull up a new window.  On the sidebar of the new window, click on `Number`.
- Then, under `Category` click on `Custom`.
- In the textbox shown under `Format Code`, type in `[Black][<0.05]0%;[White][>=0.05]0%`
- Click `Add`.

It should format the numbers outside the pie chart in your example black, and the numbers inside the pie white.  If you had different data, you could format it the same, but you would have to change the number in the brackets after the color to the number one higher than number outside of the pie. It would be like this: `[Black][`<(number one higher than number outside of the pie)`]0%;[White][`>=(number one higher than number outside of the pie)`]0%`

[Screenshot of Pie Chart Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATm3R.png)

Source:
http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/01/29/colors-in-excel-chart-labels-trick/

Comment: Thanks Julia. It looks like a plausible way to do it. I have changed some of the values and the labels are placed outside only when the values are smaller than 5%. Of course, this solution will not work if the size of the pie chart is changed, as the usable space will be smaller or bigger (in this case, I believe that changing the values in the conditions will do the trick).